# Properties of inductors with a magnetic core

Tags: inductor

If I take an Iron core,for example a simple nail, and coil wire around it, I create an inductor.

Now if I strongly magnetize the iron core, will any properties of the inductor change?

Answer (score 1):

All magnetic materials have a B-H curve as shown below where B is the flux density and H the magnetic field strength.  The effect of permanently magnetising the core is to shift this graph along the H axis.

Note \$ H \$  is the sum of \$ \frac{N \cdot I}{l}\$  where \$ N \$ is the turns of your coil, \$ I \$ current, \$ l\$ magnetic path length and the magnetic field strength from the permanent magnetisation.

The end result being that the inductor will start to saturate at a lower current in one direction and an higher current in the other.

[image]
<sub>(source: [electronics-tutorials.ws](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/electromagnetism/mag19.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are moving into saturable reactor designs: -

[image]

With a saturable reactor (aka magnetic amplifier) you can control the AC power delivered to a load (see the lamp above) with a varying amount of DC put through the control circuit. When there is no DC on the control input, the power winding (on the right) is just like a large value inductor and at 50 Hz or 60 Hz it would be designed to have an inductance that largely blocks the AC current to the lamp.

As the control DC current increases, the iron-based core will start to saturate magnetically and this reduces the power coil inductance and more current flows to the lamp and it gets brighter.

The design shown above isn't very good because the output waveform of current through the lamp is asymmetrical but there are better designs that involve two cores so that the AC waveform presented to the load is symmetrical and this type of design also reduces the power AC coupling to the control circuit: -

[image]

Details got from [here](http://www.sigmaelectricals.com/map.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in that case you will saturate the core sooner and the inductance will fall off quicker when current flows in the same  direction as the pre-biased magnetic field.

Comment: Is there any affect on the magnetic field being North or South by turning the magnet around, or is it still the same saturation?